# Guardar intervalos y extraelos de un array Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, setinterval

Buenas necesito ayuda con mi código en JavaScript. Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es guardar los identificadores de los intervalos en un array cada vez que se pulse "Derecha" 
y extraerlos del mismo para usarlos en clearInterval en la función paraMovimiento()

Tengo un elemento llamado `contenedor` que es un `<div>`.
Con la función `derecha()` hago el movimiento del contendor y con la funcion `iniciaMovimiento()` ejecutamos el movimiento que no parará hasta que llamemos a la función `paraMovimiento()`.

Quiero guardar en el array `recorrido=[]` el nº (valor) de cada intervalo al hacer click en el boton asociado a `iniciaMovimiento()`, de tal forma que cuando llame a la funcion `paraMovimiento()` esta ejecute una desaceleracion hasta que se detenga el contenedor.

¡Gracias por la ayuda de antemano!

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Mi primera página</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="libreria.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  
  var posicionX=80;
  var posicionY=80;
  var distancia=5;
  var idIntervalo;

  var contenedor;
  var saltando=false;

  var recorrido=[]

  function derecha(){
   posicionX+=distancia;
   contenedor.style.left=posicionX+'px';
  }

  function iniciaMovimiento(){
   idIntervalo=setInterval(derecha,100);
   recorrido.push(idIntervalo);
  }

  function paraMovimiento(){
   for (var i=0; i < recorrido.length ; i++){
    clearInterval(recorrido[recorrido.length].value -- );
   }
  }


  function inicio(){
   contenedor=document.getElementById('contenedor');
  }
  
  
 </script>
```

```html
 <body onload="inicio()">

 <input type="button" value="Derecha" onclick="iniciaMovimiento()">

 <input type="button" value="Para" onclick="paraMovimiento()">
 
 <div id="contenedor" style="width:65px;height:65px;position:absolute;top:80px;left:80px;background-color:blue;"></div> <br>

 

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta manera. Es bastante tosco pero te puede dar una idea.

```js
var posicionX=80;
  var posicionY=80;
  var distancia=5;
  var idIntervalo;

  var contenedor;
  var saltando=false;

  var recorrido=[]

  function derecha(){
   posicionX+=distancia;
   contenedor.style.left=posicionX+'px';
  }

  function iniciaMovimiento(){
   idIntervalo=setInterval(derecha,100);
   recorrido.push(idIntervalo);
  }

  function paraMovimiento(){
   
        let contador = x=> 1/x
        let conteo = recorrido.length +1
        recorrido.forEach(x=>
            setTimeout(
            ()=>{
                clearInterval(x)
                conteo--
            }, contador(x)*1000 )
        )
      
  }


  function inicio(){
   contenedor=document.getElementById('contenedor');
  }
```

```html
<body onload="inicio()">

 <input type="button" value="Derecha" onclick="iniciaMovimiento()">

 <input type="button" value="Para" onclick="paraMovimiento()">
 
 <div id="contenedor" style="width:65px;height:65px;position:absolute;top:80px;left:80px;background-color:blue;"></div> <br>

 

 </body>
```